# Almost sure convergence of bivariate Borel functions.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and we are given Borel functions $h_n:\Omega\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ $(n\in\mathbb{Z}_+)$ and $h:\Omega\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for all $\omega_0\in\Omega$, $h_n(\omega_0,\,\cdot\,)$ converges almost surely to $h(\omega_0,\,\cdot\,)$. i.e.,

$$ P\Big( \omega: h_n(\omega_0,\omega) \to h(\omega_0,\omega) ~\text{as}~ n\to\infty \Big) = 1, \quad\text{for all $\omega_0\in\Omega$.} $$

In this case, is it true that $h_n(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,)$ converges almost surely to $h(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,)$? i.e.,

$$ P\Big( \omega: h_n(\omega,\omega) \to h(\omega,\omega) ~\text{as}~ n\to\infty \Big) = 1? $$

The statement looks intuitive, so would you give some clue to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $\Omega=\mathbb N$ with the power set and the measure which puts mass $\frac  1{2^{n}}$ at $n$. Let $h\equiv 0, h_n(w_0,w)=\frac 1 n$ if $w_0=w$ and $1$ otherwise. Then the hypothesis is satisfied since $h_n(w_0,w) \to h(w)$ for all $w$. But $h_n(w,w)=1 $ which does not tend to $h(w,w)$ for any $w$.

Comment: Well I think $h_n(\omega_0,\,\cdot\,)$ does not converge to $h(\omega_0,\,\cdot\,)$ in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy for idea. Here is counter example:

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $P$ is Lebesgue measure.

$$ h_n(\omega_0, \omega) = \begin{cases} n & (\omega_0 = \omega) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \quad\text{and}\quad h \equiv 0 $$.